# Mouse Over for Activity History

Tags: community

Is there a way to create a mouse over for the "Activity History" ?
[image]

I had created the following code but it  seems to not work for the Hover

```
    <apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="HoverActivityHistory1">
<apex:pageBlock title="Activity History List">
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Taskvalues}" var="acc">
<apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Task.Fields.Subject.Label}">
<a href="/{!acc.id}"
id="lookup{!acc.id}opp4"
onblur="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('lookup{!acc.id}opp4').hide();"
onfocus="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('lookup{!acc.id}opp4', '/{!acc.id}/m?retURL=/{!acc.id}&isAjaxRequest=1').show();"
onmouseout="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('lookup{!acc.id}opp4').hide();"
onmouseover="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('lookup{!acc.id}opp4', '/{!acc.id}/m?retURL=/{!acc.id}&isAjaxRequest=1').show();">
{!acc.Subject}
</a>
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Task.Fields.Description.Label}" value="{!acc.Description}" />
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Apex class

```
public class HoverActivityHistory1{

   public static List<Account> accounts; 

   public static List<Task> acc;

    public HoverActivityHistory1(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
     acc = [select Id, WhatId, Subject, Description from Task where WhatId =: ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')  ];

    }

    public static List<Task> getTaskvalues(){


    return acc;
    }




}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems to be a issue with Salesforce. This is not working for Task. Even I tried with the back end URL `https://c.na15.visual.force.com/<Object ID>/m?retURL=%2F<Object ID>&isAjaxRequest=1`. This URL gives you the inside content of the popup when `<Object ID>` is replaced by a actual ID. This is working for Standard Objects as well as custom objects but not for Tasks,